# subprocess.check_output Showing [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, subprocess

I've had this error for the past 2 or 3 days and I have no clue what I've done wrong or how to fix it

I'm starting to think it's not even the code problem its just my PC
because this was working the other day but no it's not

all it is trying to do is get my HWID then verify my HWID is in the Pastebin

I am on windows 11
and using python and subprocess

here is the error

```
File "C:\Users\myname\Desktop\python-stuff\dark\Dark.py", line 33, in <module>
    hardwareid = subprocess.check_output('wmic csproduct get uuid').decode().split('\n')[1].strip()
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 420, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 501, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 966, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1435, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

and here is the code

```
hardwareid = subprocess.check_output('wmic csproduct get uuid').decode().split('\n')[1].strip()
site = requests.get('https://pastebin.com/raw/hMX2AiWf')

try:
    if hardwareid in site.text:
        pass
    else:
        os.system("cls & title cls & title Dark - HWID Error")
        print()
        print(f' {Fore.RED}[{Fore.LIGHTCYAN_EX}ERROR{Fore.RED}] HWID Not In Database.')
        print(f' {Fore.RED}[{Fore.LIGHTCYAN_EX}HWID{Fore.RED}]: ' + hardwareid) 
        print(f' {Fore.RED}[{Fore.LIGHTCYAN_EX}Administrator{Fore.RED}] Send HWID To Administrator To Be Whitelisted.')
        time.sleep(15)
        os._exit(1) 
except:
    print(f' {Fore.RED}[{Fore.LIGHTCYAN_EX}ERROR{Fore.RED}] FAILED to connect to database')
    time.sleep(5) 
    os._exit(1)
```

I have tried adding "shell=True" to the code but then I get this error

```
'wmic' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\myname\Desktop\python-stuff\HWID\HWID.py", line 18, in <module>
    hardwareid = subprocess.check_output('wmic csproduct get uuid', shell=True).decode().split('\n')[1].strip()
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 420, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 524, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'wmic csproduct get uuid' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I really really need help
I will pay if this gets fixed
Please, someone, help me

Comment: try using `os.popen()`

Comment: where in the code would I do that? sorry I'm a bit new to this

Comment: `os.popen('wmic csproduct get uuid').read()`

Comment: @deadshot I've added it 

but now it just says "'wmic' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

and skips the HWID verifying process and just continues to the program

`
hardwareid = os.popen('wmic csproduct get uuid').read()
site = requests.get('https://pastebin.com/raw/hMX2AiWf')
`

Comment: where you running the code ide/cmd/powershell?

Answer (score 0):

wmic has been deprecated according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmic) and may have been removed in some windows update (don't have 11 myself so can't confirm).

> The WMI command-line (WMIC) utility is deprecated as of Windows 10, version 21H1 ...

With the intended interface now being powershell's [CIM cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/ps101/07-working-with-wmi). For the UUID, `Get-CimInstance` can be used with the `Win32_ComputerSystemProduct` class, from python this can be done by passing the command to `powershell.exe` like so:

```py
>>> subprocess.check_output(
    [
        "powershell.exe",
        "Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_ComputerSystemProduct | Select-Object -ExpandProperty UUID",
    ]
)

b'00000000-0000-0000-0000-D8CB8AC79XXX\r\n'
```

You can also pass the text argument to `check_output` to get a string directly instead of decoding it yourself

```py
>>> subprocess.check_output(
    [
        "powershell.exe",
        "Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_ComputerSystemProduct | Select-Object -ExpandProperty UUID",
    ],
    text=True,
)

'00000000-0000-0000-0000-D8CB8AC79XXX\n'
```